# Use TREAT to restrict subtypes in a query in Oracle

Tags: oracle11g

According to the Oracle docs, i can use `TREAT` to return a specific subtype in a query, see [Example 2-38](http://download-west.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/adobjbas.htm#i479093)

However, the docs also state that for any subtypes that aren't students (in the example), it returns NULL.

Since i am using `PUT_LINE` to output a report, with headings "STUDENT NAME: " etc, it is outputting rows of empty headings.

How can i stop this behaviour?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify the TREAT expression in the WHERE clause? Or wrap the statement in an online view and filter out the nulls in the outer portion's WHERE clause?